# Retrieving the last element of a DynamoDB table using Python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

Code:

```
import json
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key


dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb.Table('sample_table')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    response = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('visit_id').eq('0'),ScanIndexForward=False,Limit = 1)

    return response['Items']['visit_counter']ype here
```

I receive the following error message:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "list indices must be integers or slices, not str",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "requestId": "e3fe7fb8-e6e0-41e1-b8e0-d3716f5c4737",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 14, in lambda_handler\n    return response['Items']['visit_counter']\n"
  ]
}
```

I don't have a clue how to get this, and I'm not finding too many resources online to provide this information. Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried adjusting the parameter passed to KeyConditionExpression, and adjusting how to reference the parameters passed to response...not sure if these are the correct terms. This is relatively new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Even without knowing anything else, reading that error is actually useful in this case. It is telling you that you are trying to get the item from a list but trying to access a list element as if it is a `dict`

so you can deduce that response['Items']` is probably a list in this case, you would use an index like

```
response['Items'][0]  # for the first element or
response['Items'][-1] # for the last element
```

When in doubt, check AWS sdk for return values or if you have the ability, print/check the object you are getting back.

If you take a look at 'query' for dynamodb in boto3 documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.query

you will see that items is actually a list:

```
    Response Syntax

{
    'Items': [
        {
            'string': {
                'S': 'string',
                'N': 'string',
                'B': b'bytes',
                'SS': [
                    'string',
                ],
                'NS': [
                    'string',
                ],
                'BS': [
                    b'bytes',
                ],
                'M': {
                    'string': {'... recursive ...'}
                },
                'L': [
                    {'... recursive ...'},
                ],
                'NULL': True|False,
                'BOOL': True|False
            }
        },
    ],
    'Count': 123,
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `ype here` as junk on your last line. Looks like you didn’t fully delete the starter text.